# How to generate SAP RFC assembly by using SAP RFC Connector 3.0 for .NET

Tags: c#, saprfc, sap-dotnet-connector

I am new to SAP .NET connector world. I was using SAP RFC connector for .NET 2003 to build RFC and use the generated DLL to connect to SAP.
Because of server upgrade, I had to move to NCo 3.0 for .NET. This does not show up in vs 2003.

I am looking for the steps to generate RFC build assembly using SAP NCo 3.0.

Comment: SAP NCo 3.0 is quite different from connectors before.  There is no longer the proxy classes generated and all that.  Everything is contained within the reference DLL.   You can read more about the Nco here http://scn.sap.com/people/thomas.weiss/blog/2011/01/14/a-spotlight-on-the-new-net-connector-30  If you have specific questions post them on here I will be sure to try and answer them.

Comment: thanks for the help! I was able to work on the PoC